# Getting $_POST variables that contain variables

Tags: php, post

```
<?php

$var = "arbitrary";

echo <<<_END

<form method = "post" action = "feed.php">

    <input type = "text" name = "$var" />
    <input type = "submit" />

</form>

_END;

if (isset($_POST['$var']))
{
    echo $_POST['$var'];
}

?>
```

I can't seem to get this $_POST data when I try to retrieve it from the variable $var.  Is this possible? (Getting $_POST from something other than just a string)

Comment: Single quotes do not parse the variable inside. So you're looking for a variable named "$var" instead of "arbitrary" as you may expect. Change it to `$_POST[$var]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$var = "arbitrary";

?>

<form method = "post" action = "feed.php">

    <input type = "text" name = "<?php echo $var ?>" />
    <input type = "submit" />

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST[$var]))
{
    echo $_POST[$var];
}

?>
```

The issue was just the quoted `$var` in your array syntax here `$_POST['$var']` as others have mentioned. There was nothing wrong with your heredoc syntax, so if you feel more comfortable with HERDOC syntax, you should continue with it.

Comment: Yeah no problem. Sorry if I go overboard with my answers sometimes, but I like to add as much explanation as possible.

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine.  The more the merrier :) I'll add you as the accepted answer.

Comment: There is no problem with the `$var` inside the HEREDOC block. It correctly displays *arbitrary*. The comes from `$_POST['$var']`. But yes, your way is much more cleaner. ;)

Answer (score 6):

`$_POST['$var']` should be `$_POST[$var]` aka don't wrap your variable in a single quote